# HTTPS Adobe Policy crossdomain.xml Chrome / IE

Tags: ssl, adobe

With "crossdomain.xml" policy (Flash  based http apps) folder applied to Http server,

Https server is GET (failed) via Chrome /IE

The Http server is behind a Firewall, does this prevent the Policy file from being prevented?

Comment: For a ReverseProxy between Apache 2/Apache Tomcat, Apache Http2 SSL configuration is displaying the following message as "403 Forbidden " ...I have not configured any Directory Tag access,would this be the concern for Prevention of directory Access ???

Comment: I have a similar problem, but I can't change flash. It the rest sevice on the chinese resource baidu.com.
http://www.baidu.com/hw/main.swf doesn't work in chrome